# WordPress to MSWord Prefill Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, ms-word

Is it possible to pass field data using a Wordpress plugin (or any other methods) to a Word document.

What I would like to achieve is when a user hits "Download Document" link:

http://prntscr.com/6n5fg3

they will be presented with a form asking for their "Business name" (a form field for example) and that in turn prefills a document (MS Word format). See: http://prntscr.com/6n4x9u when they download.

I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of ideas to get you started.

If you want to capture the user's data, for your own purposes, you can have him fill out a form *before* he may execute the download.

You could make a fillable form in Word.  See, for example, http://www.howtogeek.com/203892/how-to-create-fillable-forms-with-ms-word-2010/

Or how about a fillable pdf based on your Word file?